# Given two risky stocks calculate the rate of return, standard deviation, beta, and risk-free rate

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, mathematics, finance-mathematics, math

> Consider a world where there are only two risky stocks, $A$ and $B$, whose details are listed in the table below:

[image]

Furthermore, the correlation between the returns of stocks $A$ and $B$ is $\rho_{A B} = \frac{1}{3}$. There is also a risk-free asset and in this world the CAPM is satisfied exactly.

> a.) What is the expected rate of return of the market portfolio?
>
> b.) What is the standard deviation of the market portfolio?
>
> c.) What is the beta of stock A?
>
> d.) What is the risk-free rate in this world?

Solution to a.): We have

$$Cov(r_A, r_B) = \frac{1}{3}(.15)(.09) = .0045$$

Recall that

\begin{align*}
\sigma^{2}_{P} &= \sigma^{2}_{A}W_A^{2} + \sigma^{2}_{B}W_B^{2} + 2\sigma_A \sigma_B cov(r_A,r_B)\\
&=  \sigma^{2}_{A}W_A^{2} + \sigma^{2}_{B}(1 - W_A)^{2} + 2\sigma_A \sigma_B cov(r_A,r_B)\\
&= .0306 W_A^{2} - .0162 W_A + .0082215\\
\frac{\partial \sigma^{2}_{P}}{\partial W_A} &= 0 \implies \boxed{W_A = .2647}
\end{align*}

Note that

$$\frac{\partial^2 \sigma^{2}_{P}}{\partial W_A^2} = .0612 > 0$$

thus the variance is at a minimum. Hence

$$E[r_P] = W_A E[r_A] + W_B E[r_B] = .1279 \approx .13$$

Solution to b.): We have

$$\sigma^2{P} = .006074$$

$$\boxed{\sigma_P =.0779}$$

For some reason that I don't fully understand, my professor in the homework has $9\%$.

I am not sure how to get question part **c.)** or **d.)** because it seems that there isn't enough information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a.) The market capitalization $m_{cap} = 100*\$1.50 + 150*\$2.0 = \$150 + \$300 = \$450$, so the weight of each asset is $1/3$ and $2/3$ respectively in the market portfolio. You don't need to find the minimum variance portfolio. If you plug in these values you get exactly $E[r_m] = 1/3*0.15 + 2/3*0.12 = 0.13.$

b.) The formula is wrong, as you multiply your covariance with the standard deviations of the assets. 
The correct formula is $$\sigma_P^2 = w_A^2\sigma_a^2 + w_B^2\sigma_b^2 + 2w_aw_b\sigma_a\sigma_b\rho_{ab} \\=1/3^2*0.15^2 + 2/3^2*0.09^2 + 2*1/3*2/3*0.0045 = 0.0080506$$
Taking the squareroot gives you a standard deviation of $9\%$.

c.) The Beta of an asset can be derived as $\beta_a = \frac{\sigma_a}{\sigma_{market}}\rho_{a,market}$. You thus need to find the correlation, or covariance, between the market and stock a.

d.) The risk-free rate of the market can be considered as implicitly defined in the CAPM formula, $$E[R_a] = R_f + \beta_a(E[R_m] - R_f).$$
When you know $\beta_a$, you get $$R_f = \frac{1}{1-\beta_a}(E[R_a]-\beta_aE[R_m])$$

Comment: For c.) thats what I thought we needed to find but I am not sure how to find the correlation or covariance between the market and stock $A$

Comment: Use the definition of covariance and what you know about how the market is defined. Maybe the rule $\sigma(X,aX+bY) = a\sigma^2_X + ab\sigma(X,Y)$ will help.

Comment: I am still having trouble with part c and d could you help?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Question d) is answered as soon as you have the answer in c). I have given you the covariance formula in the comment above. When you have the covariance, the correlation is $\rho_{a,market} = \frac{\sigma(a,market)}{\sigma_a \sigma_x}$, which you can insert directly into the formula I gave in the answer.

Comment: I don't know how to calculate the $\rho_{a,market}$

Comment: How do you find $\mathbb{E}[AM]$?